# Moving Wordpress site from MAMP to WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have developed my Wordpress website locally using MAMP on a Mac. I now would like to transfer the site to a Windows 7 computer where I have installed WAMPServer (to continue to be developed locally).

This is what I have tried:

> - Exported the wordpress database to a .sql file using phpAdmin
> - Made a copy of my entire Wordpress installation (named wordpressFiles, located in the htdocs file that was installed by default with mamp)
> - Imported the wordpress to the new computer using phpAdmin
> - Copied the wordpress installation files into the www folder created by default with WAMP Server (named wordpressFiles)
> - Using phpAdmin, under wp_options I have changed my siteurl and home from http://localhost:8888/wordpressfiles to http://localhost/wordpressfiles
> - I have enabled the Apache rewrite_module and restarted servers
> - Using a text editor I added the following lines and changed the third to:
>
> > - define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wordpress');
> > - define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');
> > - define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

After starting all WampServer services, and opening phpAdmin, I see my wordpress folder under Projects. When clicking on it, however, I get an HTTP 500 internal error message.

In wp-config.php, the MySQL settings are defined as such (I'm wondering if something is wrong here):

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

In phpAdmin on my mac, the server name is localhost while on my Windows machine, the server name is mysql wampserver. Perhaps this is an issue? If it is, nor changing to define('DB_HOST', 'mysql wampserver') nor define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1') nor define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP') fixed the issue.

Other thoughts: does this have anything to do with the .htaccess file? Some forums and posts have told me to remove this temporarily, but it turns out I don't have an .htaccess file in my www root folder.

Comment: try http://localhost/wordpressfiles/index.php and try editing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in wp_config

Comment: @pankijs Just tried both and still getting the HTTP 500 Error. See edits for the changes I made to wp-config

Comment: @user25976 Try removing the .htaccess (make a bkp first). Were you running apache on mamp or ngix? If Apache check both httpd.conf (Sounds like modrewrite is not enabled)

Comment: @Engerlost I have enabled modrewrite (Apache > Apache Modules > rewrite_module) and restarted all servers. What do you mean by "removing the .htaccess"? I found an .htaccess file under wamp/apps/phpsysinfo3.1.12. Do I just delete it?

Comment: @user25976 delete or rename the .htaccess file on the www root folder (Just to check if the project is up and running). But not that .htaccess you just mention but the one on your project's root (if any)

Comment: @Engerlost I don't have an .htaccess file on the www root folder. I've got : index.php, testmysql.php, wampserver favicon, and my wordpressFiles folder)

Comment: @user25976 Have you tried deleting those files and directly paste you wp files under www? I mean directly start your site instead of wamp start page like mamp does.

Comment: @Engerlost Just tried it and it didn't work. Trying to uninstall wamp to install xxamp and repeat process. Maybe this will work. Do let me know if you have other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete your .htacess file without any worries, this will regenerate itself when you change your permalink settings.

When you change your database settings be sure to change everything, as their may be plugins or theme dependant on certain paths being correct.

So instead of just changing it in your phpMyadmin, run the following query:

```
UPDATE cs_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'localhost:8888/paperfreeweb', 'weloveweb.co.za/paperfreeweb') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE cs_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'localhost:8888/paperfreeweb', 'weloveweb.co.za/paperfreeweb);
UPDATE cs_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'localhost:8888/paperfreeweb', 'weloveweb.co.za/paperfreeweb')
```

Where localhost:8888/paperfreeweb is the old url and weloveweb.co.za/paperfreeweb is the new url.

If this does not work, rename your plugins directory to plugins1 and create an empty plugin directory, this is to check if it might be plugins which are the issue and also move your theme folder out of the themes directory so that it defaults to the wordpress theme, to check if the theme is your issue.

Comment: I have run the query, replacing localhost:888/mysite with localhost/mysite. I have renamed plugins, and removed my theme. I don't have an .htaccess file, however. This is the only step I wasn't able to complete. I still have a 500 internal server error

Comment: Turns out I had to show hidden files before seeing my .htaccess file. After deleting it, I still didn't solve my issue

Comment: Can you access the admin backend?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The wordpress backend? Like example.com/wp-admin

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the admin backend. I logged in and now see the dashboard. I still cannot, however, access the localhost/website page. The dashboard gives me an error: "Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org..." As for the server logs....

Comment: Try to activate the default theme and check the sites front end.

Comment: Okay, I can see my site now. It's very broken, however (fonts, html formatting, images). I'm going to accept your answer, but i'm still open to suggestions

Comment: This means that your db was not exported/imported correctly... So it is not picking up your stylesheet or images. You need to get the urls right. Check out the plugin: wp-migrate-db https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ and migrate the db from the old site and import to new site. That should do it.

Comment: If you dont manage, send me the database and the new url and I can make sure it is right!!!